# diff two pipes originating from one source

Tags: shell, diff, tee

I have found the answer how to diff two pipes on SO, and the syntax is showed below.

```
diff <(./a.out) <(./a.out | sort -n)
```

However, it would create two processes of `a.out`, verified by `ps`. Is it possible to have only one `a.out`, broadcast the output into two streams, and diff on these two streams?

```
./a.out | tee >(cat) >(sort -n)
```

I can do broadcast using `tee`, but no idea how to use `diff` then.

Any suggestion?

Edit: Why I don't want to create two processes? The reason is that this is one concurrent program, so the output is non-deterministic. Therefore, I have to use the same output, from one process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your objection is to having 2 processes, but maybe you can use a fifo like this:

```
mkfifo fifo
diff <(./a.out | tee fifo) <(sort < fifo)
```

Comment: See my edit for why having 2 processes is undesirable in this case. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way if you could make use of a files

say,
./a.out > file1

cat file1 | sort -n > file2

diff file1 file2

(if at all the space is constraint or to remove unwanted files)
rm file1 file2

By end of this you will have just one a.out running and you also get the diff